# convert series to list in python

Tags: python, pandas, list

here is my `s`, first column is my  INDEX(I replace index with column ) not column and second is column

```
s =              value
      time            
12-3 19:60:00   0.42724
22-4 20:30:00   0.58799
52-4 21:50:00   0.64879
62-5 22:10:00   0.64090
62-4 23:20:00   0.75934
```

type of this `s` is  `pandas.core.series.Series` now I want to convert it to  the list like this -:

```
[['12-3 19:60:00', 0.42724],
['22-4 20:30:00', 0.58799],
['52-4 21:50:00', 0.64879],
['62-5 22:10:00', 0.64090],
['62-4 23:20:00', 0.75934]]`
```

i have done this but not directly first i convert it into Dataframe then I applied this-:

```
s.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

if I convert it directly it gives me a result like :

```
 [[Timestamp('12-3 19:60:00'), 0.42724],
 [Timestamp('22-4 20:30:00'), 0.58799]...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert index to Series first:

```
s.index = s.index.astype(str)
L = s.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Or if dont need modify index of `Series`:

```
L = s.rename_axis('a').reset_index().assign(a = lambda x: x.a.astype(str)).values.tolist()
```

**Sample**:

```
print (s)
time
2015-12-03 19:40:00    0.42724
2015-04-22 20:30:00    0.58799
Name: value, dtype: float64

s.index = s.index.astype(str)
L = s.reset_index().values.tolist()
print (L)
[['2015-12-03 19:40:00', 0.42723999999999995], ['2015-04-22 20:30:00', 0.58799]]

L = s.rename_axis('a').reset_index().assign(a = lambda x: x.a.astype(str)).values.tolist()
print (L)
[['2015-12-03 19:40:00', 0.42723999999999995], ['2015-04-22 20:30:00', 0.58799]]
```